# React js What am I supposed to do with an object that used before componentDidMount() is invoked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react component

```
    class GroceryContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        debugger;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:333/Api/grocery") 
            .then(result=> {
                return result.json();
            })
            .then(data =>{
                debugger;
                this.setState({ Ingredients: data.Ingredients })}
            );
    }

    render() {
        return (    
        <div>
            <h2>Grocery List</h2>
            <GroceryItems ingredients={this.state.Ingredients}/>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

I get error

> Cannot read property 'Ingredients' of null.

It seems to be because I am using Ingredients before the data is fetched. How do I prevent this problem? Do I just initialize it in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set default state in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    Ingredients: undefined,
  };
}
```

Note: Only set initial state like this in the constructor. All other local state updates should go through `this.setState`.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, initialize the state in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Ingredients: []
    };
}
```

And don't render your grocery list until you have items in your `Ingredients` array.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.Ingredients.length === 0) {
        return <div>Loading...</div> 
    }

    return (    
        <div>
            <h2>Grocery List</h2>
            <GroceryItems ingredients={this.state.Ingredients}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Or would it be better if I did     render() {
        if(!this.state.Ingredients){
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }  
        return (  
        <div>
            <h2>Grocery List</h2>
            <GroceryItems ingredients={this.state.Ingredients}/>
        </div>);

Comment: That would work too but I would also recommend an initial state.  I updated my answer to reflect this.